# How to change bibliography style so that writer's last name on the front?

Tags: biblatex

I'm a total noob in latex world, but i need to write in latex for my thesis. I just want the writer's name is in the front of each entry, but i dont know which style to use and how to use it.

Here is the [unexpected results](http://1drv.ms/1km2aTl). You can notice it is alphabetically sorted by the last name, but the first name is still on the front.

Here's the `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,makeidx]{skripsi}

\usepackage[bahasa]{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[style=ieee,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\defbibheading{bibliography}{\chapter*{Bibliography}}

\addbibresource{stream_video_net.bib}

\makeindex{} \centerchapter \makeatletter \doublespacing
\makeatother
\parindent 3.0em
%===================================================================
\setlength{\textwidth}{15.0cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{2.5cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{2.5cm}        
\setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\topmargin}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\headheight}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\headsep}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\footskip}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-4cm}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\pagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\tableofcontents{}

\listoffigures \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}

\listoftables \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}

\newpage
\pagestyle{headings}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1} 
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BIBLIOGRAPHY} 
\pagestyle{plain}
\printbibliography
\pagebreak
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\include{daftarlampiran}
\end{document}
```

and the `.bib` file

```
% This file was created with JabRef 2.9.2.
% Encoding: UTF-8

@ELECTRONIC{apache,
  author = {anonym},
  month = {1},
  year = {2014},
  title = {What is Apache Web Server},
  howpublished = {Online},
  url = {http://httpd.apache.org/ABOUT_APACHE.html},
  owner = {noersetiawan},
  timestamp = {2014.01.30}
}

@ELECTRONIC{mobileburn,
  author = {anonym},
  month = {1},
  year = {2014},
  title = {What is "Frame Rate"?},
  howpublished = {Online},
  url = {http://www.mobileburn.com/definition.jsp?term=fps},
  owner = {noersetiawan},
  timestamp = {2014.01.30}
}

@ELECTRONIC{openssh,
  author = {anonym},
  month = {1},
  year = {2014},
  title = {OpenSSH Documentation Page},
  howpublished = {Online},
  url = {http://www.openssh.org/},
  owner = {noersetiawan},
  timestamp = {2014.01.30}
}

@ELECTRONIC{red,
  author = {anonym},
  year = {2014},
  title = {High Frame Rate Video},
  howpublished = {Online},
  organization = {RED},
  url = {http://www.red.com/learn/red-101/high-frame-rate-video},
  owner = {noersetiawan},
  timestamp = {2014.01.30}
}

@ELECTRONIC{wan,
  author = {anonym},
  year = {2014},
  title = {Difference between LAN, MAN, and WAN},
  howpublished = {Online},
  url = {http://www.differencebetween.co.in/computers/difference-between-lan-man-and-wan/},
  owner = {noersetiawan},
  timestamp = {2014.01.30}
}

@ELECTRONIC{avermedia,
  author = {anonym},
  month = {12},
  year = {2013},
  title = {HTTP/TCP vs. RTP/UDP},
  howpublished = {Online},
  organization = {AverMedia},
  address = {47358 Fremont Blvd., Fremont, CA 94538},
  url = {http://solutions.avermedia.com/?q=en/support/knowledge-base/internet-basic/http-tcp-vs-rtp-udp},
  owner = {noersetiawan},
  timestamp = {2013.12.31}
}

@ELECTRONIC{diffen,
  author = {anonym},
  month = {12},
  year = {2013},
  title = {TCP vs UDP},
  howpublished = {Online},
  organization = {Diffen},
  url = {http://www.diffen.com/difference/TCP_vs_UDP},
  owner = {noersetiawan},
  timestamp = {2013.12.31}
}

@ELECTRONIC{princeton,
  author = {anonym},
  month = {12},
  year = {2013},
  title = {Metropolitan Area Network},
  howpublished = {Online},
  organization = {Princeton Univeristy},
  address = {Princeton, NJ 08544, United States},
  url = {http://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Metropolitan_area_network.html},
  owner = {noersetiawan},
  timestamp = {2013.12.31}
}

@ELECTRONIC{vlc,
  author = {anonym},
  month = {12},
  year = {2013},
  title = {Online Documentation of VLC},
  howpublished = {Online},
  url = {http://www.videolan.org/doc/vlc-user-guide/en/ch01.html},
  owner = {noersetiawan},
  timestamp = {2014.01.30}
}

@STANDARD{MOS,
  title = {Subjective video quality assessment methods for multimedia applications},
  organization = {International telecommunication Union, ITU-T Recommendation P.910},
  author = {anonym},
  year = {1996},
  owner = {noersetiawan},
  timestamp = {2014.01.30}
}

@ELECTRONIC{bth,
  author = {Vasanthi Dwaraka Bhamidipati and Swetha Kilari},
  month = {12},
  year = {2013},
  title = {Effect of Delay/ Delay Variable on QoE in Video Streaming},
  howpublished = {Online},
  organization = {Blekinge College of Technology},
  address = {Valhallavägen, 371 41 Karlskrona, Sweden},
  url = {http://www.bth.se/com/mscee.nsf/attachments/5297_Effect_of_Delay_Delay_Variation_on_QoE_in_Video_Streaming_pdf/$file/5297_Effect_of_Delay_Delay_Variation_on_QoE_in_Video_Streaming.pdf},
  owner = {noersetiawan},
  timestamp = {2013.12.31}
}

@ELECTRONIC{videoband,
  author = {Brad},
  month = {1},
  year = {2014},
  title = {How Fast Does Your Network Needs To Be?},
  howpublished = {Online},
  organization = {About},
  url = {http://compnetworking.about.com/od/speedtests/tp/how-fast-does-your-network-need-to-be.htm},
  owner = {noersetiawan},
  timestamp = {2014.02.07}
}

@ELECTRONIC{gafferongames,
  author = {Gleen Fiedler},
  year = {2014},
  title = {UDP vs TCP},
  howpublished = {Online},
  url = {http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/udp-vs-tcp/},
  owner = {noersetiawan},
  timestamp = {2014.01.30}
}

@ARTICLE{vlclow,
  author = {Giovanni Gualdi and Rita Cucchiara and Andrea Prati},
  title = {Low-Latency Live Video Streaming over Low-Capacity Network},
  journal = {Eighth IEEE International Symposium on Multimedia, 2006.},
  year = {2006},
  volume = {8},
  pages = {449-456},
  owner = {noersetiawan},
  timestamp = {2014.01.30}
}

@ARTICLE{traffic,
  author = {Stephen Hemminger},
  title = {Network Emulation with NetEm},
  journal = {Open Source Development Lab},
  year = {2005},
  note = {NetEm is available is tool from tc},
  owner = {noersetiawan},
  timestamp = {2014.01.30}
}

@ELECTRONIC{plymouth,
  author = {Asiya Khan},
  month = {12},
  year = {2013},
  title = {Video Mean Opinion Score (MOS) Test},
  howpublished = {Online},
  organization = {University of Plymouth},
  address = {Plymouth University, Plymouth PL4 8AA, United Kingdom},
  url = {http://www.tech.plymouth.ac.uk/spmc/staff/akhan/mostest/default.htm},
  owner = {noersetiawan},
  timestamp = {2013.12.31}
}

@ELECTRONIC{mcgath,
  author = {Gary McGath},
  month = {12},
  year = {2013},
  title = {Basics of Streaming Protocols},
  howpublished = {Online},
  url = {http://www.garymcgath.com/streamingprotocols.html},
  owner = {noersetiawan},
  timestamp = {2013.12.31}
}

@ELECTRONIC{osi,
  author = {Bradley Mitchell},
  month = {1},
  year = {2014},
  title = {OSI Model Reference Guide},
  howpublished = {Online},
  url = {http://compnetworking.about.com/cs/designosimodel/a/osimodel.htm},
  owner = {noersetiawan},
  timestamp = {2014.01.30}
}

@ELECTRONIC{utl,
  author = {Mario Serafim Nunes},
  month = {12},
  year = {2013},
  title = {Quality of Service of Video Streaming},
  howpublished = {Online},
  organization = {Instituto Superior Tecnico},
  address = {Instituto Superior Tecnico, Universidade de Lisboa.},
  url = {http://comp.ist.utl.pt/pdeec-qs/bibliografia/50-QoS%20Video%20streaming.pdf},
  owner = {noersetiawan},
  timestamp = {2013.12.31}
}

@ELECTRONIC{streamingmedia,
  author = {Jan Ozer},
  month = {8},
  year = {2012},
  title = {What Is a Streaming Media Protocol?},
  howpublished = {Online},
  organization = {Information Today Inc.},
  url = {http://www.streamingmedia.com/Articles/Editorial/What-Is-.../What-Is-a-Streaming-Media-Protocol-84496.aspx},
  owner = {noersetiawan},
  timestamp = {2013.12.31}
}

@ELECTRONIC{digitaltrends,
  author = {Drew Pindle},
  month = {12},
  year = {2013},
  title = {Best Media Streaming Services},
  howpublished = {Online},
  organization = {Digital Trends},
  url = {http://www.digitaltrends.com/home-theater/best-media-streaming-services/},
  owner = {noersetiawan},
  timestamp = {2013.12.31}
}

@ARTICLE{netem,
  author = {Junaid Shaikl and Thair Nawaz Minhas and Patrik Arlos and Markus
    Fiedler},
  title = {Evaluation of Delay Performance of Traffic Shappers},
  journal = {International Workshop on Security and Communication Networks},
  year = {2010},
  owner = {noersetiawan},
  timestamp = {2014.01.30}
}

@ELECTRONIC{norway,
  author = {Jie Xu and Liyuan Xing and A. Perkis and Yuming Jiang},
  month = {12},
  year = {2011},
  title = {On the Properties of Mean Opinion Scores for Quality of Experience
    Management},
  howpublished = {Online},
  organization = {Norwegian University of Science and Technology},
  address = {Høgskoleringen 1, 7491 Trondheim, Norway},
  url = {http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6123396&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D6123396},
  owner = {noersetiawan},
  timestamp = {2013.12.31}
}
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of replacing the link to your latex file with the contents of the file itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have `skripsi.cls` so I've used the standard `book` document class.

Simply adding the line

```
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
```

in the preamble solves the problem.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[style=ieee,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\defbibheading{bibliography}{\chapter*{Bibliography}}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\addbibresource{stream_video_net.bib}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\pagestyle{plain}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]